# Clear web browser's local database on logout

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have the following remote/local databases synced by PouchDB.

```
const db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/mydb', {skipSetup: true});

const local = new PouchDB('local_db');

local.sync(db, {live: true, retry: true}).on('error', 
console.log.bind(console));
```

I intend to clear the local databases, i.e. LevelDB database (for IndexedDB) and SQLite databases (for Web SQL) when I call `logout` like below:

```
db.logout().then(res=>{
    // Can you clear local databases?
}).catch(err=>{
    window.console.log('Error: ', err)
})
```

I wonder how I can do that.

To prevent someone who has access to the user's machine, from looking at the local databases.

Comment: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#delete_database

Comment: @Phonolog Thanks, `local.destroy()` worked